# WordPress: parsecsv.lib.php doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

Im trying to include `parsecsv.lib.php` to my wordpress plugin, but for some reasons it doesn't work. PHP debug is on, and there are no errors in the code at all, thats what strange about it.

So here's the code to include the file:

```
require_once('lib/csv.library.php');
```

the path and the filename is correct.

And here's the code to get data from CSV file:

```
<?php
$pwsCsv = new parseCSV();
$pwsCsv->encoding('windows-1251','utf-8');
$pwsCsv->auto('events.csv');
?>
<div>
   <?php foreach ($pwsCsv->data as $key => $row): ?>
      <div>
         <span><?=$row['#'];?></span>
         <span><?=$row['start_date']?></span>
         <span><?=$row['city']?></span>
         <span><?=$row['name']?></span>
      </div>
   <?endforeach;?>
</div>
```

And it doesn't return anything, if i use default code to get CSV:

```
$pwsCsv = new parseCSV('events.csv');
print_r($pwsCsv->data);
```

It return an empty array. So what could be possibly wrong? The code above works perfectly in a simple PHP file on the server, but doesn't work in WordPress. What am I missing?

Comment: Where is the events.csv located relative to the file being ran?

Comment: Try $pwsCsv->auto(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'events.csv');

Comment: I tried that, and tried adding the full path to the file, but it doesn't work either..

Comment: Actually that worked: `if (!defined('IBCCTEVENETSIMPORTER_PLUGIN_DIR')) define('IBCCTEVENETSIMPORTER_PLUGIN_DIR', WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . IBCCTEVENETSIMPORTER_PLUGIN_NAME);`   `$pwsCsv->auto(IBCCTEVENETSIMPORTER_PLUGIN_DIR . '/events.csv');`